# Javascript - How to put a callback in a callback?

Tags: javascript

I have read this:

[Callback in a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805760/callback-in-a-callback)

And I still do not understand how I am meant to do it. Sorry, I am a Python programmer and only just starting to understand JavaScript.

I have this function:

```
this.getName(function() {
alert("Done");
});
```

Which has a callback to here:

```
this.getName = function(callback){
    *doing something*
    callback();
}
```

Which works great. The alert doesn't go off until `getName()` has finished.

However I have another function, which needs to be run after `getName()` has been run and completed:

```
this.getDetails = function(){
  *Does something*
}
```

But I haven't got a clue how it is meant to be implemented. I have tried putting it in the first function, but it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

I have tried this:

```
this.getName(function(getDetails) {
alert("Done");
this.getDetails();
});
```

Comment: "I have tried putting it in the first function, but it doesn't work." Then show your attempts so we can tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ill add that now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of alerting "done", just call `getDetails` (or do both):

```
this.getName( _ => {
    this.getDetails();
} );
```

I switched to an arrow function to use lexical `this`, but if you don't want to use an arrow function you can also use bind:

```
this.getName( function ( ) {
    this.getDetails();
}.bind( this ) );
```

or just:

```
this.getName( this.getDetails.bind( this ) );
```

Comment: @ScoutEU The problem with what you had tried was that you lose `this` context when you call a function like `func()` instead of `obj.func()`, so you need to use one of these solutions to preserve your value of `this`. See this question for more details about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Paul. Thank you so much. Works perfectly. Spent several hours trying to work everything out, and it was as 'simple' as this! THANK YOU! I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as I can.